# Fluid Template doesn't load

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I'm building a site with Fluid Template. I have created two different front-end layouts and two different back-end layout but I always get this error #1288085266: No template has been specified. Use either setTemplateSource() or setTemplatePathAndFilename(). Accordingly to Typo3 Wiki this should be a solution [Exception/CMS/1288085266](http://wiki.typo3.org/Exception/CMS/1288085266)

but not in my case. This is my code:

```html
config.doctype = html5

page = PAGE
page {
 includeCSSLibs.bootstrap = https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css
 includeCSS.style = fileadmin/templates/rka2015/css/style.css
 
 includeJSlibs.jquery = https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js
 includeJSlibs.bootstrap = https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js
 includeJS.custom = fileadmin/templates/rka2015/js/custom.js
}
 
page.10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
page.10 {
  
  file = fileadmin/templates/rka2015/layouts/main_layout.html
  layoutRootPath = fileadmin/templates/rka2015/layouts/
  patialRootPath = fileadmin/templates/rka2015/partials/
  
  variables {
   siteName = TEXT
   siteName.value = rka2015
   
   contentMain < styles.content.get
   contentMain.select.where = colPos = 0
   
   content_column_1 < styles.content.get
   content_column_1.select.where = colPos = 1
   
   content_column_2 < styles.content.get
   content_column_2.select.where = colPos = 2
 }  
}


page.10.file.stdWrap.cObject = CASE
page.10.file.stdWrap.cObject 
 {
    key.data = levelfield:-1, backend_layout_next_level, slide
    key.override.field = backend_layout
    
    default = TEXT
    default.value = fileadmin/templates/rka2015/main_1_column.html
    1 = TEXT
    1.value = fileadmin/templates/rka2015/main_1_column.html
    2 = TEXT
    2.value = fileadmin/templates/rka2015/main_2_column.html
}
```

I have already checked all; section name is OK, ID for back-end layouts are ok, template is defined, everything seem to be as it should be. I really don't have a clue where else to search.

UPDATE!!!

Seems like there is a problem with a file path. I am running my site on a subdomain and it looks like that ts doesn't find the file paths if they are defined only as fileadmin/... Any thoughts? Thanks

**SOLUTION**!

```html
page {
 includeCSSLibs.bootstrap = https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css
 includeCSS.style = fileadmin/templates/rka2015/css/style.css
 
 includeJSlibs.jquery = https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js
 includeJSlibs.jquery.external = 1
 includeJSlibs.bootstrap = https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js
 includeJS.custom = fileadmin/templates/rka2015/js/custom.js
}

page.10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
page.10 {
    template = CASE
    template {
      key.data = levelfield:-1,backend_layout_next_level,slide
      key.override.field = backend_layout

      1 = FILE
      1.file = fileadmin/templates/rka2015/main_1_column.html

      2 = FILE
      2.file = fileadmin/templates/rka2015/main_2_column.html
    }
    partialRootPath = fileadmin/templates/rka2015/partials/
    layoutRootPath = fileadmin/templates/rka2015/layouts/
    variables {
 
   siteName = TEXT
   siteName.value = rka2015
   
   contentMain < styles.content.get
   contentMain.select.where = colPos = 0
   
   content_column_1 < styles.content.get
   content_column_1.select.where = colPos = 1
   
   content_column_2 < styles.content.get
   content_column_2.select.where = colPos = 2
  }
}
```

Comment: Is `file = fileadmin/templates/rka2015/layouts/main_layout.html` correct? Isn't maybe `file = fileadmin/templates/rka2015/main_layout.html` or `file = fileadmin/templates/rka2015/templates/main_layout.html` or something correct?

Comment: Hi Jost, thanks. Paths are correct, I've checked them.

Answer (score 0):

at the first look it looks right... but check your file paths, maybe they are wrong as "Jost" commented.

i'm not sure but i think the problem is that the template path (file = ...) is the same as layout root path...

by the way... if you include external styles and javascripts you need to set something like the follows i think...

```
includeJSlibs.jquery = https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js
includeJSlibs.jquery.external = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

First, check out if TYPO3 can read the file by overwriting the page object by appending this to the end of your template:

```
page.10 >
page.10 = FILE
page.10.file = fileadmin/templates/rka2015/layouts/main_layout.html
```

If that doesn't generate a page with the raw, uninterpreted output of your template file, then theres something wrong with either the file path or file permissions.

Secondly, in Fluid, Templates and Layouts are different things with different uses and should propably not be put into the same directory.

Most importantly, theres something wrong with the backend layout switch you're trying to build with the CASE in page.10.file.stdWrap.cObject . You see, the stdWrap object actually wraps around the text you've already set. If stdWrap cant find a pipe to figure out how to wrap, it just appends instead. Remove the line where you set the file in the top part and only leave the stdWrap case and you should be good to go.

Comment: Hi, thanks. First part is OK, it has generated a page with the raw but that with CASE it doesn't work. I have removed file=... and left only CASE part and I get the same error. Accordingly to Typo3 Wiki there must be file definition otherwise it won't function.

Comment: Done. I've rewritten the code a little bit and now is OK. Still don't have clue where was the problem, but it seems like it was in TS. New code is on top unter update 2.

Comment: Sorry under solution. Thanks

Comment: As I said, in your code above you had set a complete filename in .file as well as in .stdWrap. TYPO took the stdWrap and appended it to the filename, resulting in fileadmin/templates/rka2015/layouts/main_layout.htmlfileadmin/templates/rka2015/main_1_column.html which is not a file it could find.

Comment: True, but in my first code that also didn't worked and that's why I've rewritten all together. Thanks for your help!